# How can my WCF service recover from unavailable message queue?

Tags: wcf, msmq, netmsmqbinding, msmq-wcf

I have a WCF service that receives messages from the Microsoft Message Queue (`netMsmqBinding`).

I want my service to recover if the message queue is unavailable. My code should fail to open the service, but then try again after a delay.

I have code to recognize the error when the queue is unavailable:

```
static bool ExceptionIsBecauseMsmqNotStarted(TypeInitializationException ex)
{
    MsmqException msmqException = ex.InnerException as MsmqException;
    return ((msmqException != null) && msmqException.HResult == (unchecked((int)(0xc00e000b))));
}
```

So this should be straightforward: I call `ServiceHost.Open()`, catch this exception, wait for a second or two, then repeat until my `Open` call is successful.

The problem is, if this exception gets thrown once, it continues to be thrown. The message queue might have become available, but my running process is in a bad state and I continue to get the `TypeInitializationException` until I shut down my process and restart it.

Is there a way around this problem? Can I make WCF forgive the queue and genuinely try to listen to it again?

---

Here is my service opening code:

```
public async void Start()
{
    try
    {
        _log.Debug("Starting the data warehouse service");
        while(!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(_dataWarehouseWriter);
                _serviceHost.Open();
                return;
            }
            catch (TypeInitializationException ex)
            {
                _serviceHost.Abort();
                if(!ExceptionIsBecauseMsmqNotStarted(ex))
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            await Task.Delay(1000, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error("Failed to start the service host", ex);
    }
}
```

And here is the stack information. The first time it is thrown the stack trace of the inner exception is:

> at [System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqQueue.GetMsmqInformation(Version& version, Boolean& activeDirectoryEnabled)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/MsmqQueue.cs,164)
>
> at [System.ServiceModel.Channels.Msmq..cctor()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/Msmq.cs,23)

And the top entries of the outer exception stack:

> at [System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqChannelListenerBase`1.get_TransportManagerTable()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/MsmqChannelListenerBase.cs,76)
>
> at [System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer..ctor(TransportChannelListener listener)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/TransportManager.cs,182)

Comment: So you're saying even though you catch the exception, there is a bad state that is still associated?

Comment: @N-ate: That's my guess as to what's going on. (Even though I catch the exception, abort the Service Host and create a new Service Host)

Comment: I wonder if this is something related to the executionContext or synchronizationContext.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have made the source code to WCF visible, so now we can work out exactly what's going on.

The bad news: WCF is implemented in such a way that if the initial call to `ServiceModel.Start()` triggers a queueing error there is no way to recover.

The WCF framework includes an internal class called `MsmqQueue`. This class has a [static constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/Msmq.cs,21). The static constructor invokes [GetMsmqInformation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/MsmqQueue.cs,164), which can throw an exception.

Reading the [C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) on static constructors:

> If a static constructor throws an exception, the runtime will not invoke it a second time, and the type will remain uninitialized for the lifetime of the application domain in which your program is running.

There is a programming lesson here: Don't put exception throwing code in a static constructor!

The obvious solution lies outside of the code. When I create my hosting service, I could add a service dependency on the message queue service. However, I would rather fix this problem with code then configuration.

Another solution is to manually check that the queue is available using non-WCF code.

The method [System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.messagequeue.exists?view=netframework-4.7.1) returns `false` if the message queue service is unavailable. Knowing this, the following works:

```
private const string KNOWN_QUEUE_PATH = @".\Private$\datawarehouse";

private static string GetMessageQueuePath()
{
    // We can improve this by extracting the queue path from the configuration file
    return KNOWN_QUEUE_PATH;
}

public async void Start()
{
    try
    {
        _log.Debug("Starting the data warehouse service");
        string queuePath = GetMessageQueuePath();
        while(!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (!(System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Exists(queuePath)))
            {
                _log.Warn($"Unable to find the queue {queuePath}. Will try again shortly");
                await Task.Delay(60000, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            }
            else
            {
                _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(_dataWarehouseWriter);
                _serviceHost.Open();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(System.OperationCanceledException)
    {
        _log.Debug("The service start operation was cancelled");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error("Failed to start the service host", ex);
    }
}
```